# Very new JQuery Beginner- magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am extremely new to Javascript and although some is intuitive, I feel moderately lost.
Trying to create a Jquery Magnific-popup website to showcase vimeo videos since it is a free plugin.
I would like thumbnails to link to this pop-up script.

I find myself getting very confused about what files to include and which to not use since I am  new to Javascript.

I have been working with this website:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#mfp-build-tool

Which scripts do I use and which do I leave out to do that?
Please help! I appreciate any help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you unsure about including?  The Magnific documentation is pretty good for that at the link you pasted.

Basically you'll get the 3 files they say, and include them in the order you see on their page.  CSS, then jquery then magnific.  Your paths to those files will vary depending on where you save them.

The Vimeo stuff, I've no idea.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply- I guess it's more of confusion about which script to include in magnific-popup to get the desired effect. I do not think i am supposed to include every code on the page? even if I do include the desired scripts it just seems to not work? I will continue to work on this and see what my fault is. thanks again

Comment: It is not at all unusual to include multiple files to achieve one effect with JavaScript.  One of them is jQuery - think of it as an addition to JavaScript which gives Magnific a platform to build on, another is Magnific itself, and one is a CSS file which controls how everything looks.  You'll include the 3 files they list on the site you provided, then follow the "Initialization" step where you'll write some jQuery to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can look Jquery stuff, it may help you to solve all your Javascript needs. First of all, JQuery is nothing but, its Javascript package, it have many useful predefined functions, properties and more... first look the JQuery page 
http://jquery.com/
if you looking popup forms, just look the  link
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a very simple example for a pop-up image:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 

        <!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

        <!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
        <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="test-popup-link" href="img/img.jpg">Open popup</a>

    </body>
    <footer>
        <script>
            $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({ 
              type: 'image'
                // other options
            });
        </script>

    </footer>
</html>
```